# Image do not render in production - NextJS React project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, png, render, production

I created a ReactJS project based on a tutorial useng NextJS. When running locally, the logo image on the top left corner render perfectly. However, in production, after deploying in Netlify or Vercel, The logo on top left corner do not render.

I researched and found that tere is an issue related to NextJS image rendering. However I could not fix it on my onw project.

The logo is located on the component Navbar.jsx
line 55:

```js
<Link>
  <Image 
    src='/../public/assets/navLogo.png' 
    alt='/' 
    width={125} 
    height={50}
  />        
</Link>
```

vercel (production):
https://portfolio-next-js-tiagoc0sta.vercel.app/

git repo:
https://github.com/tiagoc0sta/portfolio-next-js.git

Comment: Hi! I see you changed the code to use an svg file for the logo. Are you going to stick witht that? To use svg-s in a next project you either need to use something like SVGR package or paste the svg content to the code.

Comment: Hi !  I made a test converting png to svg and it rendered correctly on production. However, the svg quality of the logo was not good anymore.

What is the best aproach to deal with images on Next.JS ?
On the turorial that I folowed, it was used png. Do you recomend that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally checked your package.json file and realized you're using next v13. It is now using a new next image component with different styling than in previous version. I suggest you check the official documentation on vercel page.
But to test it out, edit your code like this:

```
<div style={{position:"relative", height:"200px", width:"280px"}}>
  <Image src={source} alt="" fill style={{objectFit:"cover"}}/>
</div>
```

Make sure that the images' parent div is relatively positioned and has some dimensions set.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I checked again on the documentation and now it worked ! 
At the moment it is like thtat:

import navLogo from '../public/assets/navLogo.png';

....
<Image src={navLogo} alt='logo' width={125} height={50} />

All goo. Thanks for the support